# Items in File provider extension for ios 11

Tags: ios, swift, ios11, ios-extensions

I have an app with file provider extension in it. I tried giving support to the new file app with the ios 11 using this [link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/fileprovider/content_and_change_tracking/defining_your_file_provider_s_content)

I did what is instructed in this but no item is getting displayed. I have added this `NSExtensionFileProviderSupportsEnumeration = YES` in my plist as well.

`ProviderEnumerator` is my NSFileProviderEnumerator class where `ProviderItem` is a NSFileProviderItem. inside my enumerator class I have this,

```
func enumerateItems(for observer: NSFileProviderEnumerationObserver, startingAt page: NSFileProviderPage) {        
    observer.didEnumerate([ProviderItem(name: "raghav", type: "public.folder", identifier: "12334444", parentId: "-1"), ProviderItem(name: "panth", type: "public.folder", identifier: "12334444", parentId: "-1")])        
    var myInt = 100
    let myIntData = Data(bytes: &myInt, count: MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: myInt))
    observer.finishEnumerating(upTo: NSFileProviderPage(rawValue: myIntData))        
}
```

`observer.didEnumerate()` gets called but the view is not getting populated

Am I missing something **!!**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally I figured out the problem here, that if we want to show the files in the root page the `NSFileProviderItem` requires it's parent_id as `NSFileProviderItemIdentifier.rootContainer`. Setting this solved my problem