# File not getting displayed using NSFileProviderExtension

Tags: ios, swift, ios11, ios-extensions

I'm trying to implement `NSFileProviderExtension`, for the first step, I'm just trying to display a single item.

I override this method in my extension:

```
override func enumerator(for containerItemIdentifier: NSFileProviderItemIdentifier) throws -> NSFileProviderEnumerator {
    var maybeEnumerator: NSFileProviderEnumerator? = nil
    if (containerItemIdentifier == NSFileProviderItemIdentifier.rootContainer) {
        // TODO: instantiate an enumerator for the container root
        print("Root Container")
        maybeEnumerator = FileProviderEnumerator(enumeratedItemIdentifier: NSFileProviderItemIdentifier(rawValue: "rootContainer"))
    } else if (containerItemIdentifier == NSFileProviderItemIdentifier.workingSet) {
        // TODO: instantiate an enumerator for the working set
        print("Working Set")
    } else {
        // TODO: determine if the item is a directory or a file
        // - for a directory, instantiate an enumerator of its subitems
        // - for a file, instantiate an enumerator that observes changes to the file
        print("Other Stuff")
    }
    guard let enumerator = maybeEnumerator else {
        print("Enumerator Is nil, Throwing Error")
        throw NSError(domain: NSCocoaErrorDomain, code: NSFeatureUnsupportedError, userInfo:[:])
    }
    return enumerator
}
```

And this method in `FileProviderEnumerator`:

```
    func enumerateItems(for observer: NSFileProviderEnumerationObserver, startingAt page: NSFileProviderPage) {
    /* TODO:
     - inspect the page to determine whether this is an initial or a follow-up request

     If this is an enumerator for a directory, the root container or all directories:
     - perform a server request to fetch directory contents
     If this is an enumerator for the active set:
     - perform a server request to update your local database
     - fetch the active set from your local database

     - inform the observer about the items returned by the server (possibly multiple times)
     - inform the observer that you are finished with this page
     */


    let items = [FileProviderItem(id: "1", name: "1_file")]
    observer.didEnumerate(items)
    print("Finish Enumerating")
    observer.finishEnumerating(upTo: nil)
}
```

Nothing shows up right now.
Is there anything else I should do to display only a single item?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is here:
[Items in File provider extension for ios 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46563336/items-in-file-provider-extension-for-ios-11)

You have to implement **itemIdentifier, filename, typeIdentifier and parentItemIdentifier** properties to show FileProviderItem. They are required, other properties are optional.

When an user open your app's file provider in files app, the system calls **enumerator(for:)** method and it passes the **rootContainer** constant. So, you must to set **parentItemIdentifier** to **NSFileProviderItemIdentifier.rootContainer** for your item in root-level folder.

If you implement above, your item will shown.

Comment: Any idea why my folders look like files? I set `typeIdentifier` to `(NSString*)kUTTypeDirectory` but they still look like plain files and tapping them tries to preview the file instead of navigating inside. The Info panel does say they are directories.